# To find objects of the same value using Queue.contains() in C#, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, queue

I try to find coordinate values with the same values.
And I'm going to link three coordinate values.

I am doing this to make mesh at Unity.

I first found the same coordinates by bfs method.

And there is a problem trying to connect the three adjacent coordinates.

[image]

I did the following to find out if there are any adjacent points in eight directions.

```
private int[,] fx = new int[8, 2] { { -1, 0 }, { -1, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, 
                                    { -1, 0 }, { -1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 1 } };

private int[,] fy = new int[8, 2] { { -1, -1 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, -1 }, { -1, 0 }, 
                                    { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

void CreateTriangle()
{
    int index = 0;
    while (SegNode.Count > 0)
    {
        Node curNode = SegNode.Peek();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {


            Node nextNode = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 0], curNode.y + fy[i, 0], curNode.color);
            Node nextNode2 = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 1], curNode.y + fy[i, 1], curNode.color);

            Debug.Log("CurNode " + curNode.x + " , " + curNode.y + 
                " NextNode " + nextNode.x + " , " + nextNode.y + 
                " NextNode2 " + nextNode2.x + " , " + nextNode2.y);


            if (SegNode.Contains(nextNode) && SegNode.Contains(nextNode2))
            {
                newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(curNode) + index);
                newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(nextNode) + index);
                newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(nextNode2) + index);
            }
        }
        index++;
        SegNode.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

there is clearly a point about (0,1) (1,0), but I can't find it using Queue.Contains()

Maybe Contains() don't recognize it because I used [new] to create a new object.
How can I find an object?

Here is my full code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class MeshCreator : MonoBehaviour
{

// This first list contains every vertex of the mesh that we are going to render
public List<Vector3> newVertices = new List<Vector3>();

// The triangles tell Unity how to build each section of the mesh joining
// the vertices
public List<int> newTriangles = new List<int>();

// The UV list is unimportant right now but it tells Unity how the texture is
// aligned on each polygon
public List<Vector2> newUV = new List<Vector2>();


// A mesh is made up of the vertices, triangles and UVs we are going to define,
// after we make them up we'll save them as this mesh


private Mesh mesh;
// Start is called before the first frame update

private int[,] pixel = new int[15, 15] {
                                        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
                                        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
                                       };


private bool[,] visit = new bool[15, 15];

private int[] dx = new int[4] { 0, 1, -1, 0 };
private int[] dy = new int[4] { 1, 0, 0, -1 };

public int idx = 0;

public class Node
{
    public int x, y, color;

    public Node(int x, int y, int color)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }
}


public Queue<Node> SegNode = new Queue<Node>();

void bfs(int r, int c, int color)
{
    Queue<Node> q = new Queue<Node>();
    q.Enqueue(new Node(r, c, color));

    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        Node curNode = q.Dequeue();
        SegNode.Enqueue(curNode);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int tr = curNode.x + dx[i];
            int tc = curNode.y + dy[i];

            if (tr >= 0 && tr < 15 && tc >= 0 && tc < 15)
            {
                if (!visit[tr, tc] && pixel[tr, tc] == color)
                {
                    visit[tr, tc] = true;
                    q.Enqueue(new Node(tr, tc, color));

                    newVertices.Add(new Vector3(tr, tc, 0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private int[,] fx = new int[8, 2] { { -1, 0 }, { -1, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, 
                                    { -1, 0 }, { -1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 1 } };
private int[,] fy = new int[8, 2] { { -1, -1 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, -1 }, { -1, 0 }, 
                                    { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };


void CreateTriangle()
{
    int index = 0;
    while (SegNode.Count > 0)
    {
        Node curNode = SegNode.Peek();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {


            Node nextNode = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 0], curNode.y + fy[i, 0], curNode.color);
            Node nextNode2 = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 1], curNode.y + fy[i, 1], curNode.color);

            Debug.Log("CurNode " + curNode.x + " , " + curNode.y + 
                " NextNode " + nextNode.x + " , " + nextNode.y + 
                " NextNode2 " + nextNode2.x + " , " + nextNode2.y);


            if (SegNode.Contains(nextNode) && SegNode.Contains(nextNode2))
            {
                newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(curNode) + index);
                newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(nextNode) + index);
                newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(nextNode2) + index);
            }
        }
        index++;
        SegNode.Dequeue();
    }
}



void Start()
{

    //int result = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < 15; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 15; c++)
        {
            if (!visit[r, c] && pixel[r, c] != 0)
            {
                newVertices.Add(new Vector3(r, c, 0));
                bfs(r, c, pixel[r, c]);
                //result++;
            }
        }
    }

    CreateTriangle();

    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

classes are **reference types**. That means your `SegNode` queue doesn't actually contain values but **references** to instances of `Node`.

As you said already your `Contains` check doesn't work like that since you are checking if the same reference to the excatly same instance of `Node` exists in the queue.

---

You could simply make your `Node` a **value type** instead by changing it from a `class` to a `struct`

```
public struct Node
{
    public int x, y, color;

    public Node(int x, int y, int color)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

than your check

```
Node nextNode = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 0], curNode.y + fy[i, 0], curNode.color);
Node nextNode2 = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 1], curNode.y + fy[i, 1], curNode.color);

Debug.Log("CurNode " + curNode.x + " , " + curNode.y + 
          " NextNode " + nextNode.x + " , " + nextNode.y + 
          " NextNode2 " + nextNode2.x + " , " + nextNode2.y);

if (SegNode.Contains(nextNode) && SegNode.Contains(nextNode2))
{
    //...
}
```

should work.

---

Alternatively you can use e.g. [Linq FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) like

```
var nextNode = SegNode.FirstOrDefault(n => n.x == curNode.x + fx[i, 0] 
                                        && n.y == curNode.y + fy[i, 0]);

var nextNode2 = SegNode.FirstOrDefault(n => n.x == curNode.x + fx[i, 1] 
                                        && n.y == curNode.y + fy[i, 1]);

if(nextNode != null && nextNode2 != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

- `FirstOrDefault` returns the first match defined by the predicate e.g.

  ```
  n.x == curNode.x + fx[i, 0] && n.y == curNode.y + fy[i, 0]
  ```

  or `null` if no matches are found or the list/queue is empty

---

as a broader alternative you could also let your `Node` implement [IEquatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1) but that's maybe a bit overkill for your usecase ;)