# Algorithm for duplicating problem resolution during search process for mesh dynamic generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, breadth-first-search

Assume a 2D array size of 513 * 513 is a coordinate value.

I want to dynamically generate a mesh by connecting coordinates of the same value.

The value of a 2D array is randomly generated.

Using the bfs alorithm, Vertex of teh same vlue was all entered.

And to make a mesh by connecting three adjacent points, it takes too long to search the same value among the eight points in the adjacent direction.

This seems to have occurred, including redundancy.

I want you to share ideas for solving redundancy.

Below is the entire source code,the CreateTriangle() function causes duplication.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class SegmentationMeshCreator : MonoBehaviour {
    // This first list contains every vertex of the mesh that we are going to render
    public List<Vector3> newVertices = new List<Vector3>();

    // The triangles tell Unity how to build each section of the mesh joining
    // the vertices
    public List<int> newTriangles = new List<int>();

    // The UV list is unimportant right now but it tells Unity how the texture is
    // aligned on each polygon
    public List<Vector2> newUV = new List<Vector2>();


    // A mesh is made up of the vertices, triangles and UVs we are going to define,
    // after we make them up we'll save them as this mesh

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private Mesh mesh;

    public Queue<Node> SegNode = new Queue<Node>();


    private bool[,] visit = new bool[513, 513];


    private int[] dx = new int[4] { 0, 1, -1, 0 };
    private int[] dy = new int[4] { 1, 0, 0, -1 };

    // 8 - direction
    private int[,] fx = new int[8, 2] { { -1, 0 }, { -1, 0 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, 
                                        { -1, 0 }, { -1, 0 }, { 0, 1 }, { 0, 1 } };
    private int[,] fy = new int[8, 2] { { -1, -1 }, { 0, -1 }, { -1, -1 }, { -1, 0 },
                                        { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

    public struct Node
    {
        public int x, y, color;

        public Node(int x, int y, int color)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.color = color;
        }
    }

    void bfs(int r, int c, int color, int[][] pixel)
    {
        Queue<Node> q = new Queue<Node>();
        q.Enqueue(new Node(r, c, color));

        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            Node curNode = q.Dequeue();
            SegNode.Enqueue(curNode);
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                int tr = curNode.x + dx[i];
                int tc = curNode.y + dy[i];

                if (tr >= 0 && tr < 513 && tc >= 0 && tc < 513)
                {
                    if (!visit[tr, tc] && pixel[tr][tc] == color)
                    {
                        visit[tr, tc] = true;
                        q.Enqueue(new Node(tr, tc, color));

                        newVertices.Add(new Vector3(tr, tc, 5));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateTriangle()    
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (SegNode.Count > 0)
        {

            Node curNode = SegNode.Peek();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                var a = SegNode.Any(o => o.x == curNode.x + fx[i, 0] && o.y == curNode.y + fy[i, 0] && o.color == curNode.color);
                var b = SegNode.Any(o => o.x == curNode.x + fx[i, 1] && o.y == curNode.y + fy[i, 1] && o.color == curNode.color);

                if(a && b)
                {
                    Node nextNode = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 0], curNode.y + fy[i, 0], curNode.color);
                    Node nextNode2 = new Node(curNode.x + fx[i, 1], curNode.y + fy[i, 1], curNode.color);

                    newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(curNode) + index);
                    newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(nextNode) + index);
                    newTriangles.Add(SegNode.ToArray().ToList().IndexOf(nextNode2) + index);
                }
            }
            index++;
            SegNode.Dequeue();
        }
    }

    public void createMesh(int[][] pixel)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < 513; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < 513; c++)
            {
                if (!visit[r, c] && pixel[r][c] != 0)
                {
                    newVertices.Add(new Vector3(r, c, 5));
                    bfs(r, c, pixel[r][c], pixel);

                }
            }
        }
        CreateTriangle();


        _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Create a Mesh");

        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = newVertices.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = newTriangles.ToArray();
        mesh.uv = newUV.ToArray(); // add this line to the code here
        //mesh.Optimize();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
           createMesh(pixel);           // int pixel[][]
    }
}
```

When the red dot is the reference point, as shown in the figure above, there is a problem of duplication, which is making three more mesh for the same points during an 8-way search.

[image]

If you are curious about my project, you can refer to my question before.

[How to create a mesh dynamically In unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063656/how-to-create-a-mesh-dynamically-in-unity)

[To find objects of the same value using Queue.contains() in C#, Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095183/to-find-objects-of-the-same-value-using-queue-contains-in-c-unity)

Comment: Well i understan why you want to use bfs since you have random coordinates but since you are in 2D why don't you sort the points first and then triangulate them based on index number?

Answer (score 0):

Since in `createMesh()` you iterate over the points first by row and the by column I assume for point `x` that your already created all possible triangles for the points above `x` and the point left from `x`.

Then you only need to check if `x` creates a triagle with the points below `x` and right of `x`.

Comment: @HanSeobKim did my solution helped you. If not what causes Problems